# Java JLabel SetIcon update change the JLabel Zorder

Tags: java

[image]
[image]

I have two JLabels that I need to put one over the second. The first time the page loaded correctly. I made a button for changing the Icon (JFileChooser) but once validated it changes its ZOrder to come in the front :

```
    File newI = new File(user.getProfilepic());
    BufferedImage newIBuff;
    try {
        newIBuff = ImageIO.read(newI);
        BufferedImage NewIm = resizeImage(newIBuff, labelpic.getWidth(),        labelpic.getHeight());
        labelpic.setIcon(new ImageIcon(NewIm));
        labelpic.setComponentZOrder(labelpic, 1);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: try to use [layered panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)

Comment: Thanks but I just found the fix by removing and re-adding the JLabel then Repainting.